# How to get week birthdays

Tags: caml-query

I have a list called **Profile**, and this list contains the *Birthday* field of type DateTime.
I created two fields of type calculated, one gets the day, and the other gets the birthday month of field.
And I have to make a query to get the birthdays of the week
I thought of mounting a filter like this:

```
Select Name, Day, Moth from Profile 
Where (Day = 14 And Moth = 10) Or (Day = 15 And Moth = 10) Or (Day = 16 And Moth = 10) 
   Or (Day = 17 And Moth = 10) Or (Day = 18 And Moth = 10)
   Or (Day = 19 And Moth = 10) Or (Day = 20 And Moth = 10)
```

Only I have no idea how to do this in CAML, can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to create a calculated field BirthdayCheck which contains the birthday, but with a fixed year like 2000. Formular to use: `=DATE(2000,MONTH(Birthday),DAY(Birthday))`

Then your query would be

```
Select Name, Day, Moth from Profile  
Where BirthDayCheck => 2000-10-14 and BirthDayCheck <= 2000-10-20
```

Which in CAML would be

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="BirthdayCheck" />
      <Value Type="Calculated">2000-10-14T00:00:00Z</Value>
    </Geq>
    <Leq>
      <FieldRef Name="BirthdayCheck" />
      <Value Type="Calculated">2000-10-20T00:00:00Z</Value>
    </Leq>
  </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to create this new calculated field returns the following error: No support for formula or it contains a syntax error.

Comment: If your locale is using , as decimal point you may have to write the formular as `=DATE(2000;MONTH(Birthday);DAY(Birthday))`

Answer (score -1):

2000(y)-12(m)-14(d) and BirthDayCheck <= 2000(y)-01(m)-14(d)

This query will fail here.. If we are checking for current and next year.

Comment: Hi Chetan, maybe you should use the real year instead of 2000 for the query work, or do you store all birthdays as in 2000 regardless?